# Getting error like need struct type but got string in spark scala for simple struct type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my schema

```
root
 |-- DataPartition: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TimeStamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialAsReportedLineItemName: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _languageId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialLineItemSource: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialStatementLineItemSequence: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialStatementLineItemValue: double (nullable = true)
 |-- FiscalYear: long (nullable = true)
 |-- IsAnnual: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsAsReportedCurrencySetManually: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsCombinedItem: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsDerived: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsExcludedFromStandardization: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsFinal: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsTotal: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- ParentLineItemId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodPermId: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _objectTypeId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ReportedCurrencyId: long (nullable = true)
```

From the above schema i am trying to do like this

```
val temp = tempNew1
      .withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName", $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._VALUE")
      .withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName_languageId", $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._languageId")
      .withColumn("PeriodPermId", $"PeriodPermId._VALUE")
      .withColumn("PeriodPermId_objectTypeId", $"PeriodPermId._objectTypeId").drop($"AsReportedItem").drop($"AsReportedItem")
```

I don't know what i am missing here .
I get below error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Can't extract value from FinancialAsReportedLineItemName#2262: need
>   struct type but got string;

Comment: your first `withColumn` make `FinancialAsReportedLineItemName` as `string`, so your second call definitely won't work.

Comment: @nabongs ok so i need to create another data frame and then need to extract it ?

Comment: nope, just change name of column in first call, e.g `withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName_VALUE", $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._VALUE")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to access `FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._languageId` when `FinancialAsReportedLineItemName` column has been replaced by `FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._VALUE`

you should be changing the following two lines

```
.withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName", $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._VALUE")
.withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName_languageId", $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._languageId")
```

to

```
.withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName_value", $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._VALUE")
.withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName_languageId", $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._languageId")
```

If `FinancialAsReportedLineItemName_value` column name is supposed to be `FinancialAsReportedLineItemName` then you should be swapping the `withColumns` as

```
.withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName_languageId", $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._languageId")    
.withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName", $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._VALUE")
```

Comment: But then i need to rename column again