# Unable to convert my dataframe to dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

CustomerAccountOutput2.printSchema()
val CustomerAccountOutputDS: Dataset[CustomerAccountOutput] = CustomerAccountOutput2.as[CustomerAccountOutput]

Comment: This is how my Dataframe looks like.

root
 |-- totalBalance: long (nullable = true)
 |-- avgBalance: double (nullable = true)
 |-- numberAccounts: long (nullable = false)
 |-- customerId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- forename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- surname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- accounts: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

Comment: I am trying to run the below to convert, However it is throwing the error as mentioned below.
val CustomerAccountOutputDS: Dataset[CustomerAccountOutput] = CustomerAccountOutput2.as[CustomerAccountOutput]

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from lambdavariable(MapObject, StringType, true, 38): need struct type but got string
  at

Comment: perhaps of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128580/getting-error-like-need-struct-type-but-got-string-in-spark-scala-for-simple-str